# Why is that I am getting named error while running memory_profiler?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, memory-profiling

I am trying to profile the below mentioned small piece of Python code. The function 'get_ph' is stored in a file 'hs.py' in the same working directory.

The function code in the 'hs.py' file is:

```
def get_ph(hs, ps, dp):
    hs_np= np.array(hs)
    ps_np = np.array(ps)
    dsh = hs_np[ps_np == dp]
    return dsh
```

I have also tried adding the numpy import statement within the function as below.

```
def get_ph(hs, ps, dp):
    import numpy as np
    hs_np= np.array(hs)
    ps_np = np.array(ps)
    dsh = hs_np[ps_np == dp]
    return dsh
```

The code for running the memory profile is:

```
import numpy as np
hs = ['a','b','c','d','e']
ps = ['x','y','y','x','x']

from hs import get_ph
%reload_ext memory_profiler
%mprun -f get_ph get_ph(hs, ps, "x")
```

Why is that I am getting the below named error when I run the above code? By the way if I change the code in the function by not converting the lists into numpy arrays and execute, it works perfectly well. Appreciate inputs why 'np'  is thrown as a NameError.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1524/2740015597.py in <module>
      5 
      6 get_ipython().run_line_magic('reload_ext', 'memory_profiler')
----> 7 get_ipython().run_line_magic('mprun', '-f get_ph get_ph(hs, ps, "x")')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2349                 kwargs['local_ns'] = self.get_local_scope(stack_depth)
   2350             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2351                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2352             return result
   2353 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decorator.py in fun(*args, **kw)
    230             if not kwsyntax:
    231                 args, kw = fix(args, kw, sig)
--> 232             return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
    233     fun.__name__ = func.__name__
    234     fun.__doc__ = func.__doc__

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\memory_profiler.py in mprun(self, parameter_s, cell)
    986 
    987         try:
--> 988             profile.runctx(arg_str, global_ns, local_ns)
    989             message = ''
    990         except SystemExit:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\memory_profiler.py in runctx(self, cmd, globals, locals)
    766         self.enable_by_count()
    767         try:
--> 768             exec(cmd, globals, locals)
    769         finally:
    770             self.disable_by_count()

<string> in <module>

~\Jupyter Notebooks\........\hs.py in get_ph(hs, ps, dp)
      1 def get_ph(hs, ps, dp):
----> 2     hs_np= np.array(hs)
      3     ps_np = np.array(ps)
      4     dsh = hs_np[ps_np == dp]
      5     return dsh

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Comment: Well, did you actually `import numpy as np`?

Comment: Ah,, Yes, Of course .. I did import numpy as np. Making the correction top the code here.

Comment: I mean inside `hs.py`.

Comment: If you mean in the 'get_ph' function inside the 'hs.py' file, I have tried that too. However, I don't think that is necessary. In any case, the result is same, same error.

Comment: The question was whether `import numpy as np` is done at global scope in  `hs.py`. You showed us some other unnamed module that does the import and then `from hs import get_ph`. But the unnamed module's import doesn't put `np` in the `hs` namespace. You don't have to put the import in the function, but you do have to put it in the module.

Comment: Hi, hs is nothing hs.py file which contains get_ph function. I have added the import numpy as np command both in the function as well as in my Jupyter session. The error persists.

Comment: As I have mentioned, if I don't convert the lists into numpy arrays and use a slightly different code in the function as required to deal with the lists, the code works.